# where are foreign lists and how to query them?

Tags: 2013, rest, odata

I use REST/JSON to query Sharepoint 2013 where "expand" helps me to retrieve the authors name from a foreign list.

```
.../_api/lists/getbytitle('list1')/items?$select=*,Author/Title&$expand=Author
```

Because selecting Author/* does not work I'm having a hard time finding out the fieldnames of that list.

```
.../_api/lists/getbytitle('list1')/items?$select=*,Author/*&$expand=Author
```

Due to my lack of understanding where those foreign lists reside I haven't been able to find them in my sharepoint-installation. Asking Google and MSDN could not help me either. I found some basic concepts - but none of them provided that information.

So where can I find those foreign lists and query them?

Where can I find a list of those lists - "Author" doesn't seem to be the only one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you need ListName or ListGuid of Lookup field ?

You can get it from /_api/lists/getbytitle('list1')/Fields - here you find Author Lookup field and Guid of list you are looking for.

Inside of Field XML you get this, like in my example:

```
<d:LookupList>{5cc890cb-1974-4142-9939-c41c2539e03e}</d:LookupList>
```

To get all items inside of Lookup list:
_api/web/Lists(guid'5cc890cb-1974-4142-9939-c41c2539e03e')/items

Use PostMan or some similar plugins to display this XML more friendly.

It would be better to describe the main goal. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've created a newsslider for our SP-startpage. My new task is to add user information to each of those newssheets (name, department, picture). The goal is to achieve this without initating separate queries for each sheet. "expand=Author" seemed to do the trick, but I could not find out the right fieldnames - at least until your reply.

But since userpic-URL's aren't accessible I don't think there is a way around those extra requests...